# How to display a website in the background of blocks and interact with it?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have some HTML and CSS code that creates a page with several blocks. When a block is clicked, I want to display a specified website in the background of the blocks, directly behind them, so that the blocks hover over the website. Here’s my code:

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
        const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
        blocks.forEach(block => {
            block.addEventListener('click', () => {
                iframe.src = block.dataset.url;
            });
        });
```

```css
.container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .column.right {
        align-items: flex-end;
        }
        .block {
            width: 150px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
        .block:hover {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .left .block:hover {
            margin-right: 50px;
        }
        .right .block:hover {
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .background {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        iframe {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -2;
            border: none;
        }
```

```html
 <iframe></iframe>
    <div class="background">
        <!-- background -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column left">
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.bing.com">Block 1</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.microsoft.com">Block 2</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.google.com">Block 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.wikipedia.org">Block 4</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.youtube.com">Block 5</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.amazon.com">Block 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried adding an event listener to each block that listens for a click event and changes the background of the .background element to display an iframe with the desired website. However, I’m not able to interact with the website in the background because the blocks are covering it.

Is there a way to display a website in the background of the blocks and interact with it directly on the page? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: All you have shown is some very basic HTML/CSS - nowhere are there references to other websites nor any attempt to draw content from those.

Comment: sorry i added my javascript and some edited code

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Block Background Changer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column left">
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.bing.com">Block 1</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.microsoft.com">Block 2</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.google.com">Block 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.wikipedia.org">Block 4</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.youtube.com">Block 5</div>
            <div class="block" data-url="https://www.amazon.com">Block 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <iframe id="background-iframe"></iframe>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



 body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100vh;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.block {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    cursor: pointer; /* Add cursor pointer for better UX */
}

.block:hover {
    width: 200px;
}

.left .block:hover {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.right .block:hover {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: transparent; /* Use a transparent background */
}

iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
    border: none;
}

const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
const backgroundIframe = document.getElementById('background-iframe');

blocks.forEach(block => {
    block.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const url = block.getAttribute('data-url');
        backgroundIframe.src = url;
    });
});
```

you can try these changes and check them the changes that I made are

Key changes and explanations:

Moved the background  above the iframe element in the HTML to ensure that it's positioned behind the blocks.

Added overflow: hidden; to the body in CSS to prevent scrollbars from appearing when the iframe loads content.

Added cursor: pointer; to the .block class in CSS to indicate that the blocks are clickable.

Added an id attribute to the iframe (background-iframe) to target it using JavaScript.

Moved the script to an external JavaScript file (script.js) for better separation of concerns.